# Ruby on Rails: How to chain strong parameter if some of the parameters are nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have the following parameters:

```
"struct"=> {"content" => nil}, "name" => "structA"
```

When I try to build a strong parameters filter around it:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new("struct"=> {"content" => nil}, "name" => "structA")
params.permit(:struct, :name)
```

It only accept name:

```
=> {"name"=>"structA"}
```

I read some of the post that for the nested attribute, I need to use "require":

```
params.require("struct").permit!
```

But how can I chain the nested and non-nested attribute as one filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
params.permit(:struct => [:content], :name)
```

Comment: Do you mean this: params.permit({:struct => [:content]}, :name)